# How to specify Apache Commons Mail content-type in a single method?

Tags: scala, jakarta-mail, email

http://commons.apache.org/email/api-1.0/org/apache/commons/mail/Email.html

Writing a new wrapper for sending mail in my Scala app. I've been browsing through the Apache Commons Mail library and it's great except I'm confused by the `setContent` method. Docs show this is the only method that asks for content-type, but it has two parameters: `content` and `contentType`.

In my mailer I am already defining a text and html message body, so how would I specify the content-type by itself? Code below:

```
var email: HtmlEmail = new HtmlEmail
    email.sethtmlMsg(bodyHtml)
    email.setTextMsg(bodyText)

    email.setCharset(current.charset)

    setAddress(current.from) { (address, name) => email.setFrom(address, name) }
    setAddress(current.replyTo) { (address, name) => email.addReplyTo(address, name) }
    current.recipients.foreach(setAddress(_) { (address, name) => email.addTo(address, name) })
    current.ccRecipients.foreach(setAddress(_) { (address, name) => email.addCc(address, name) })
    current.bccRecipients.foreach(setAddress(_) { (address, name) => email.addBcc(address, name) })

    email.setSubject(current.subject)
    email.updateContentType(current.contentType)
```

The `updateContentType` isn't a real method, so do I need to again pass the message content or can I pass a `null` into the first parameter for `setContent`? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out because I am specifying an `HtmlEmail` when I use the methods `setHtmlMsg` and `setTextMsg` Apache Commons Mail will automatically define the content-type of each message part.

Therefore a single method to define a content-type is not at all necessary unless using the `org.apache.commons.Email.setContent` where you're getting hands-on with setting message content.

Most of the problem was due to a lack of my understanding about emails ;)